# curl using socks5 proxy and IPv4

Tags: curl, proxy, ipv6, ipv4, socks5-proxy

When using `curl` with socks5 proxy, seems that my IPv4 addressing is gone:

```
$ env ALL_PROXY=socks5h://localhost:8001 curl -4 ipconfig.io
2607:xxxxxxxx:681f

$ curl -4 ipconfig.io
97.xx.xx.116
```

What is the problem and how to ensure `curl` still uses IPv4 when using socks5 proxy?

Comment: Same issue here, probably a curl bug. Have you reported it?

Comment: No @bparker, as I was not sure whose problem it was and I don't know how to report bug to curl. Would you take care of it please?